# Iterating through a HashMap containing objects java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following HashMap:

```
Map<String,List<Objects>> abc = new HashMap<String,List<Objects>>()
```

How can I iterate through the objects, to access the properties of the object?

Comment: Note that possible duplicates and related question appear when writing the question.

Comment: Iterate over `key-value` entries to get `value` which would be list of your objects and iterate over each of this lists. I assume you know how to iterate over list. To know how to iterate over `key-value` entries check link provided by Luiggi.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Entry<String, List<Object>> e : abc.entrySet()){
  String key = e.getKey();
  for(Objects o : e.getValue()){
     System.out.println(o.toString());
  }   
}
```

Comment: Please try to add more details to your answer!